# how to configure smtp settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I wanted to recover password using PasswordRecovery control in asp.net .but when I clicked on submit button .I have got this message that :

Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server
.
this is my html code:

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" 
          style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small" 
          onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail" >
          <MailDefinition BodyFileName="../User Pages/RecoveryPass.htm" From="info@shirinfam.com"
            IsBodyHtml="True" Subject="بازیابی کلمه ی عبور" Priority="High"></MailDefinition>
        <UserNameTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                                        Text="<%$ Resources:resource, passrecovery %>" 
                                        style="font-size: small; font-family: Tahoma"></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="<%$ Resources:resource, submit %>" 
                                        ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1" Font-Names="tahoma" 
                                        Font-Size="X-Small" Width="80px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </UserNameTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        smtp.Send(e.Message);
    }
```

and this is smtp settings in web.config
:

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings >
      <smtp >
        <network host="mail.domainname.com" userName="info@dominname.com" password ="password" defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
          </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your `credentials` for your email account, let's say you are using the your `Gmail` account to send email, So, you have to set the `credentials (username and password)` to your `smtpClient object`.

Following is the example::

```
 MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
 SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
```

MailMessage helps us to create the mail and SmtpClient allows us to send mail to the reciepient.

NOTE: the following code is configured to send mails from GMAIL account..

```
m.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "Display name");
m.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@domain.com", "Display name To"));
m.Subject = "Test";
m.Body = "This is a Test Mail";
sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
sc.Port = 587;
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password of from");
sc.EnableSsl = true; // runtime encrypt the SMTP communications using SSL
sc.Send(m);
```

Comment: these arent solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

DefaultCredentials should be set to true, and should explicitly add the credentials to the client.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server, port);
        // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
        // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```